# unable to change log level in the server side

Tags: java, log4j

Below is the code for working with log4j and inserting log statements in my application.

web.xml
Modified the web.xml and included the below lines.

```
  <context-param>
        <param-name>log4jConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/log4j.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.util.Log4jConfigListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
```

log4j.xml : It is in WEB-INF folder

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE log4j:configuration SYSTEM "log4j.dtd">
<log4j:configuration debug="true" xmlns:log4j='http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/'>
    <appender name="console" class="org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender">
        <param name="Target" value="System.out" />
        <param name="Threshold" value="debug" />
        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
            <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d %-5p %c{1}:%L %m %n" />
        </layout>
    </appender>

    <appender name="fileAppender" class="org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender">
        <param name="Threshold" value="INFO" />
        <param name="Threshold" value="debug" />
        <param name="maxFileSize" value="30MB" />
        <param name="maxBackupIndex" value="10" />
        <param name="file" value="${catalina.home}/logs/myAppLog.log"/>
        <param name="append" value="true" />
        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
            <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L %m %n" />
        </layout>
    </appender>

    <!--  3rdparty Loggers -->
    <logger name="org.springframework.core">
        <level value="info" />
    </logger>

    <logger name="org.springframework.beans">
        <level value="info" />
    </logger>

    <logger name="org.springframework.context">
        <level value="info" />
    </logger>

    <logger name="org.springframework.web">
        <level value="info" />
    </logger>

    <!-- Root Logger -->
    <root>
        <priority value="debug"></priority>
        <appender-ref ref="fileAppender" />
    </root>

</log4j:configuration>
```

I want to change the log level from debug to info/error at server side and without restarting the server it has to apply the log level, but it is not taking the modified log level. Any suggestions?
How can i change the log level at the server side and the change should effect as soon as i modify the file. Server is tomcat and log4j1.2.17.jar is the jar file i'm using.

Answer (score 0):

Try add this to `web.xml`:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>log4jRefreshInterval</param-name>
    <param-value>10000</param-value>
</context-param>
```

Comment: Doesn't need to restart server ?

Comment: @jingx - +1, doesn't it take load on the server ?

Comment: @user8190500 I don't get your question. It does create a monitor thread, hence some extra load on the server, if that's what you mean.